# In Objective-C, how can I change the property of an instance inside of class via UIControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontrol

This question is about the exercise 6.9 of iOS Programming 4th Edition.
I have a class that can draw concentric circles and respond to touches by changing its color randomly.

Here is the implementation of the view:

```
@implementation LTHypnosisView
- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self){
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.circleColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    return self;
}    

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //Draw the circles
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    float red = (arc4random() % 100) /100.0;
    float green = (arc4random() % 100) /100.0;
    float blue = (arc4random() % 100) /100.0;
    UIColor *randomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
    self.circleColor = randomColor;
}

- (void) setCircleColor:(UIColor *)circleColor{
    _circleColor = circleColor;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

Here is the implementation of the viewController:

```
@implementation LTHypnosisViewController
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    CGRect screenRect = self.view.bounds;
    LTHypnosisView *mainView = [[LTHypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    [self addSubview:mainView]
    NSArray *items = @[@"Red",@"Green",@"Blue"];
    UISegmentedControl *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
    [segControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(change:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, 60);
    segControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    segControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:segControl];
}

- (void) change:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        //How should I write here??
    }
}

@end
```

I want to change the color of the concentric circles with the `UISegmentedControl`. Consequently I need a method within the viewController to change the _circleColor property of the LTHypnosisView instance. How can I do that?

Comment: Post the headers of your `LTHypnosisView` and `LTHypnosisViewController` classes. In your `LTHypnosisViewController` you'll need to create an outlet to your `LTHypnosisView`

Comment: LTHypnosisView: `- (void) setCircleColor:(UIColor *)circleColor;`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way, I'd make `LTHypnosisView *mainView` a property of the view controller, make `setCircleColor` public, and then in `change:` method call `[self.mainView setCircleColor:myColor];`

You could also do something more involved, like define a protocol on `LTHypnosisView` and set the view controller as the datasource.  Whenever the `change:` method is called, call something like `[mainView updateColor]` and within `updateColor` have it read the color from it's datasource.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and it did solve my problem! But I'm extremely new to obj-c so, could you please tell me how to do the thing "more involved"?

Comment: I thought this was helpful when to do option 1 vs option 2 in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352832/datasource-pattern-versus-setting-properties-while-configuring-objects

Comment: And this for a tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-delegation--cms-23901